# Charset - json_encode with utf-8

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I know there are many questions to this problem and I've read most of them, of course including 'UTF-8 all the way through'.
Following those examples and hints I reduced everything to this minimal example - which unfortunately still won't print a german umlaut `ö` after json_encoding an array:
(and *here is the question* - why? what else can I do?)

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<br>ini_get('default_charset') ". ini_get('default_charset')."<br>"; // nothing shown
// if (!ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8')) {  // won't work (I guess I'm not allowed to do that)
// echo "could not set default_charset to utf-8<br>";
// }

echo "Köln"; // yay! displays "Köln" as expected

$darr = Array();
$locationString = mb_convert_encoding("location", "UTF-8");
$darr[$locationString] = mb_convert_encoding("Köln", "UTF-8");
$json = json_encode($darr); 
echo $json;
// output:
// {"plain":"K\u00f6ln","utf_encode":"K\u00c3\u00b6ln","utf_decode":"K"}
// dah? why?
$array = json_decode($json); 
var_dump($array);
// ... even worse: "KÃ¶ln"

phpinfo();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

relevant system info:
*php 5.2.5 (yeah, I know. I can't change it)*

from phpinfo():
default_charset    no value

*json*
json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1

*mbstring*
Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl

**mbstring.encoding_translation Off Off**
Could this be my problem?

...and yes, the php file is encoded utf-8 (without BOM) in sublimeText. Submitted to server via FileZilla once as ASCII, once Binary, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When encoding unicode data with json_encode you should use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag:

```
$json = json_encode($darr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

The above is available since php 5.4.0.

For older versions you can try and use this function instead:

```
function unicode_json_encode($arr) {
        //convmap since 0x80 char codes so it takes all multibyte codes (above ASCII 127). So such characters are being "hidden" from normal json_encoding
        array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$item, $key) { if (is_string($item)) $item = mb_encode_numericentity($item, array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8'); });
        return mb_decode_numericentity(json_encode($arr), array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');
}
```

> The above function was taken from the comments in [json_encode page in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: yep, I tried that. Unfortunately this throws an error - I guess my php version is too old? 'Notice: Use of undefined constant'

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it in PHP since Ver5.4.0

Comment: hmpf.... All I'm trying is to backup data in a useable format to move to a new, better server.... it's a bummer.

Comment: Check the update in my answer, it might help you during the time you move to newer server :)

Comment: well, it gave me the same output as `json_decode(json_encode($darr))` did. I guess I have to give up. php's too old. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Try remove the `mb_convert_encoding` there before using the `unicode_json_encode` function

Answer (score 0):

You simply haven't told PHP not to escape the characters when it encodes the data as JSON.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php):

> JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE (integer)
>   Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.

So:

```
$array = json_decode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: yep, I tried that. Unfortunately this throws an error - I guess my php version is too old? 'Notice: Use of undefined constant'

Comment: @Jeff: *"Available since PHP 5.4.0"*

Comment: Yes, your PHP version is too old … for anything. [Upgrade to something they provide security updates for](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: I like the "for anything".... I know. this is why I wanna export data in a useable format...

Comment: JSON with escaped Unicode characters is usable (albeit using more bytes than are really needed). Any JSON parser will decode them happily.